# Why recursion works backwards?

Tags: c++, recursion

I've a problem with understanding how this recursion works.
Why the output shows: C B A and not A B C ?

```cpp
void recur(const char* sth) {

    if (*sth != 'D') {
        recur(sth+1);
        std::cout << *sth << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){

    recur("ABCD");
}
```

At the start, I've 'ABCD',
then I'm calling recursively with 'BCD' but also in the meantime shouldn't the first call of recur function print 'A' ?

In recursive calling, recur function should again call recursively with 'CD', but also second call of recur function print 'B'

and so on...

I was convinced that even though function calls itself, the first call doesn't automatically end.

I'm aware that some of you are going to recommend me using debugger, but I didn't find there anything which would help me understand this and that is why I decided to ask for help here.

Kind regards,

Comment: "_I'm aware that some of you are going to recommend me using debugger, but I didn't find there anything which would help me understand this_" Please explain, how stepping through your code line-by-line, wouldn't help you understand this?

Comment: Because you make the recursive call before you print anything--simple as that.

Comment: This is a  brilliant example for recursion! Us old C/C++ programmers take it as staple diet but, for newbies, it's a **big part** of the learning curve!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first element is processed after all the others. Similarly, the second element is processed after all the elements that come after it, and so on.

```
void recur(const char* sth) {

    if (*sth != 'D') {
        recur(sth+1); // <- Here you are processing the rest...
        std::cout << *sth << std::endl; // <- ... before processing the current
   }
}
```

Try flipping those lines. Which also makes this into a tail recursion for extra points.

---

> I was convinced that even though function calls itself, the first call doesn't automatically end.

Correct, the function has to return, then the caller continues. If it didn't, then you would not see it output anything, given that you output after the recursive call.

> At the start, I've 'ABCD', then I'm calling recursively with 'BCD' but also in the meantime shouldn't the first call of recur function print 'A' ?

It does "print" 'A'. It does after the recursive call, which is printing everything else, resulting in 'A' being the last output.

---

I see you say "meantime". The recursive call is not waiting for the caller to complete or anything like that. Au contraire, the caller would resume after the recursive call. To be clear, after the recursive call completes, the code that comes after the call continues. *Stepping through the code with a debugger should have made that clear.*

Comment: Hmm...I've missed one break point during debugging and that is why I didn't actually see that all recur calls end first and then output is being printed in the terminal...anyway your explanation helped me so thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The order of the executed code is always important. You are calling the recur function with "ABCD", so:

if char pointer is not at 'D':
   -> calls the function again with "BCD" before you get a chance to output the current 
   position.

Just switch the output and the function call and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function again before you are getting the output you desire.

So when you first call `recur(sth+1)`, it goes into the next "instance" of that function, and it will continue to evaluate until you fail the condition. When it gets to the last call (in this case, when you reach `'C'`), then the output is printed in the console. It then proceeds "backwards", and going back to that call where you reach `'B'`, where it then executes the next line. If that wasn't clear, perhaps this code explanation might be.

```
void recur(const char* sth) { // value of char* sth is "ABCD"
    if (*sth != 'D'){
        recur(sth+1); // this adjusts the pointer, and calls the function
                      // the current function will branch to a new function
        std::cout << *sth << std::endl; // this line will not execute until the
        // last line has been fully evaluated. This remains true for all calls of recur()
    }
}
```